# How to pass a Private Map and input data

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a private map that takes a long and a string type, one being a student id and a student name. I've declared my map as so:

```
typedef map<long, string> Student;
```

I'm having trouble passing this into a setter function as I cannot access the maps methods once I try to declare Student in this function.

Ideally, I was trying to make this set method to take in some other variables I've declared from the same class and have getter and setter methods provided.

```
void SetMap(long studentId, string studentname);
{
    Student.insert(pair<long, string>(studentId, studentname);
}
```

This method would be called to take in values from a file.

I understand that I might have to pass `Student` into the parameters but I have no idea how to declare this.

I was also trying to do the same for a get method but the same problem arises.

Some advice would help a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `Student` is a type (an alias to the map), not an instantiation. So, you cannot `insert` into `Student`. You must first make an instantiation of the map `Student studentMap;`, then do `studentMap.insert(...)`

Comment: Made an answer out of my suggestion... hope this helps.

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks that worked perfectly, but i still have the problem of creating a get method to return the values output. i've tried using "const Student & classname::GetMap()" but it keeps asking for a type. whenever i try using typedef as the type it doesent like that

Comment: @Stan Depending on where you have the `typedef`, it may have specific namespacing. If your `typedef` is inside your class `ClassName` with the `studentMap` declaration, you have to use the fully-qualified name of the type, like so: `ClassName::Student`.

Comment: @Stan Also, be careful with your method-naming, to avoid confusion. Since you are not setting the entire map, but only inserting a pair of values, consider changing your method name from `SetMap` to `InsertValuesIntoMap` or something similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Student` is a type (an alias to map), not an instantiation that you can call `insert` on. You should modify your class to include a full declaration of this `Student` type like so:

```
typedef map<long, string> Student;
Student studentMap;
```

Now, you should be able to call `insert` on the instantiation of the map, `studentMap`:

```
void SetMap(long studentId, string studentname);
{
    studentMap.insert(pair<long, string>(studentId, studentname);
}
```